# Compare a color sample in Android to database of other colors?

Tags: java, php, android, sql, colors

More specifically, I need to select a color from an Android camera image and compare it to numerous (between 100-200) other solid color samples and find the closest (maybe the top 5 closest) match.

Is the easiest way to do this just to compare the RGB values of the color selected from the image with the RGB values of each of the other samples? If any quick sample algorithms can be offer, even pseudocode, would be appreciated...

Should the 100-200 color samples be stored in the Android app or would it be better if they were stored on a server and accessed through a bit of php and sql?

Familiar with java, html, css, javascript, jquery, ajax, jason, perl, and xml if these should be used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's define the **distance** between two RGB colors. One method could be to calculate the absolute difference between the R bytes, added to the absolute difference between the G bytes, added to the absolute difference between the B bytes.

Calculating this distance for two colors is trivial, you get an integer as result. To find the best 5 matches, simply go over the 100 samples and calculate the distance between your selected color to each of them, and then sort the results according to distance. The 5 smallest distances are your best matches.

If you're doing this entire calculation once for a single selected color from the camera (as opposed for example to all the pixel colors in the camera image), I see no performance trouble so there's no need to optimize further.

Holding the 100 samples inside your app is the fastest and easiest to do. There is no need to do the calculation on the server - you have a single server but many devices, use them. The only reason to communicate with a server is if your 100 samples might change periodically. Updating the samples from a server in case they've changed could be a little easier than publishing a new updated app to the Play Store. If you don't plan to change your 100 samples often, skip the server bit altogether.